# Avoid Literals In If Condition SonarQube error

Tags: java, object, sonarqube

I am getting error like `Avoid Literals In If Condition` in sonarqube , and unable to find the proper solution to it.

```
     SingleWrapper singleWrapper=null;
      :
      :
      singleWrapper=createWrapper();
      :
      private void wrap(){
           if(singleWrapper != null){  //Here i am getting error.
             //do Something
                             }
                         }
```

I know this question seems to be repeated one but its not,because previously asked for `String` .
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because your static code analysis tool detects `null` as a hardcoded literal, which, rigorously, is true.

The recommended behavior is to declare a constant object like

```
final static Object NULL = null;
```

and use it like

```
if(singleWrapper != NULL)
```

But I haven't still met a developer doing this. In this case, I think you're OK and you can ignore the code check warnings. That's my 2 cents.

Comment: But when i do so it says add cast() to SingleWrapper.

Comment: Who says? What is `cast()`? It looks like a method call.

Comment: its casting ,simple java casting,which will change it to Object to SingleWrapper

Answer (score 0):

The description for the PMD rule reads:

> Avoid using hard coded literals in conditional statements, declare those as static variables or private members.

While in most cases it is relevant (you don't want to have arbitrary hard coded string or numerical literals), in this case it is (IMHO) a bit too zealous, for checking against null is so widely used that it should probably be ignored by this rule.

Since this rule comes from PMD (not SQ internal engine), you could ask for an upstream fix - or just remove it from your profile if it really bugs you.

Note that this rule is part of the [Controversial Rules](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/rules/controversial.html) set.